# Problem when encrypting with XOR encryption with repeating key in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm new to python and stackoverflow, the problem I have with my script is that it generates a message encrypted in hexadecimal that is wrong, because when I want to decrypt it with another tool on the internet it sends me another message all badly encrypted, I think My script is encrypting the text wrong, could someone help me?

```
def repeating_key_xor(bytes_messages, key):
    output_bytes = b''
    index = 0
    for byte in bytes_messages:
        output_bytes += bytes([byte ^ key[index]])
        if (index + 1 ) == len(key):
            index = 0
        else:
            index += 1
    return output_bytes

def main():
    message = "No soy un hombre de plegarias, pero si estas en el cielo, ¡Ayúdame Superman!".encode()
    key = "763".encode()
    ciphertext = repeating_key_xor(message,key)
    print(ciphertext.hex())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The encrypted message it generates is:

> 79591344594a17435d175e5c5a54415216575216435b535456445a56451f174656455913445f13524547564513525813525a13545f565b591f17f492764ff08d52525a531364434352445e565812

That when I want to decrypt it to test it with this tool:
https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=XOR(%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'Standard',false)

Return this message to me:

> ........... R ..... W ... RPW ................ T ......... R. .... U
>   ............... Q ....................... V ..... Q ... T ... U..U
>   ...... QP..R ..... W ............... V ......

Comment: CyberChef's `XOR` operation does not accept the input in hex format (you can specify the *key* in hex, but there's no need to do that since your key is entirely readable text).  If you insert a `From Hex` operation in front of the `XOR`, you will get your original text back.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just want to know if the encrypted message is good, so I wanted to use a tool to decrypt it and verify that it was encrypted. So, do you know if the message is well encrypted?

Comment: You have *properly applied* XOR encryption, if that's what you're asking.  That doesn't make it a *good* encryption, any sort of substitution cipher is trivially breakable given enough samples.

Comment: Ok, thank u very much!